# kable function with encoding (polish signs) in R

Tags: r, shiny, latex

I use `knitr::kable` function to dynamicly print tables in pdf with latex. 
the problem is that in the table there are polish signs, which are encoded for example:
'Galeria Mokotów' is encoded into 'Galeria MokotĂłw' and my '.Rnw' file fails. 
how should I change the preamble to fix pdf printing?

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{res}


 \usepackage{helvet} 
 \usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{fontenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitB]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{layout} % show a page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}  % dummy text



 \begin{document} 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try inserting this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  below `\documentclass`: or just this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: thanks, but it didn' help. still have an error .

**! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+81)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.190 134 & Galeria Ĺ
                        Ăłdzka & 42000 & 43181 & 43181 & 1181 & -38106 & 0...

? **

Comment: What heppens if you add this: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and remove `\usepackage{polski}"` and  `\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}`

Comment: If the above does not work try this: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F3}{\o`}

Comment: I don't know if it is a good solution.. because there are more encoded letters in the table.. How can i exclude every of them ?